# Apache permission to write on user home folder

Tags: linux, permissions

I'm performing server backup with php script and trying to save the output to home folder.
* I have there available space

Apache is the user that running the php script and don't have permission to write to my user home folder, event when i set chmod 777 to ~/backup.
I try to add symlink to this path but still there is permission issue.

Is there simple way to let Apache drop file to my home folder and still stay secured?

Comment: Which distro are you using ?

Comment: Distro is rhel 6.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all make sure that the apache user has suitable (rx) access to the ~/backup directory from / down and rwx on the ~/backup directory.

It is also likely that SELinux is playing it's part and denying httpd access to user home directories.

Check the output of

```
getsebool httpd_enable_homedirs
httpd_enable_homedirs --> off
```

If it is off as shown above then it needs to be allowed

```
setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs on
```

If this doesn't solve the problem then take a look in your audit.log and other log files for relevant messages.